# Set media position when calling playMedia - Connect SDK iOS

Tags: ios, television

How can I specify the video position when I call MediaPlayer's playMedia? I tried doing this but it doesn't work. What is the correct way of doing this?

```
[self.device.mediaPlayer playMedia:mediaURL
                               iconURL:iconURL
                                 title:title
                           description:description
                              mimeType:mimeType
                            shouldLoop:NO
                               success:^(LaunchSession *launchSession, id<MediaControl> mediaControl) {
                                   [mediaControl seek:300 success:nil failure:nil];
                               }
                               failure:^(NSError *error) {
                               }];
```

EDIT: I am casting media onto a ChromeCast device.

Comment: I am not familiar with the iOS apis but if you create callbacks for the seek call, you may get more info on its success/failure.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @AliNaddaf. I tried calling the seek method outside of that block and it complains that CastService does not have the seek method. I suspect that seeking for ChromeCast has not been implemented. Will submit an issue in Github.

Comment: `seek` has been implemented (see the api reference at https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/ios/interface_g_c_k_media_control_channel#acd37cf9b478159b07a92edc30f94977c), the name is seekToTimeInterval. It is also used in our CastVideos-ios sample on our github repo https://github.com/googlecast

Comment: Sorry, I meant for ChromeCast in Connect SDK. In their CastService class, they have not implemented seeking.

Comment: What is "Connect SDK"?

Comment: @AliNaddaf http://connectsdk.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been answered [outside](https://github.com/ConnectSDK/Connect-SDK-iOS/issues/43#issuecomment-43544562) of StackOverflow.

The answer was to call seek on the `mediaControl` object reference returned in the `displayMedia` `success` callback, rather than directly on the `ConnectableDevice`'s `mediaControl` object.

[Relevant documentation](http://connectsdk.com/docs/ios/beam-media/)